# Linux composer install error 'The openssl extension is required'

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I have use 'composer install' command and it say

```
[Composer\Exception\NoSslException]                                          
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab  
  le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error  
  , at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

I use on Linux os with php 7.2

How can I fix this?

I already look in php.ini and can't see an extension for openssl.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to disable SSL/TLS protection. but if you are confident enough with the working environment try this.

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

then

```
composer install
```

Comment: or just install it :/